# Page directive: can't have multiple occurrences of language error on tomcat 4

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat, page-directives

I get this error when i deploy my code on tomcat 4
However it is working fine on tomcat 7

I have removed all the language occurences from the JSP page but i still get this error.
Please help!!

Comment: Update your question with the error code

Comment: Tomcat 4 is based on a complete different servlet spec. If you develop you code I would recommend you always to this against your target platform.

Comment: Thanks guys issue was resolved i had multiple language="java" references on my page and removing them and keeping it in only<%@ page language="java"..  fixed it